# Hide activated submenu (toggle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I've got a great code that works - but.. I have 2 submenus.
When I click A it opens fine, but when I click B, A doesn't close so iI now got 2 submenus open.
I want B to close (if it's clicked) when I click A.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submenu').hide();
  $("li:has(ul)").click(function() {
    $("ul", this).toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
  <li>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think this could help you:
https://codepen.io/brenden/pen/Kwbpyj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `$('.submenu').hide();` in your click event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submenu').hide();
    $("li:has(ul)").click(function() {
      $('.submenu').hide();
        $("ul", this).toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    <li>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `$('ul li:has(ul)').not(this).find('.submenu:visible').toggle('slow');` to the click function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submenu').hide();
  $("li:has(ul)").click(function() {
    $('ul li:has(ul)').not(this).find('.submenu:visible').toggle('slow');
    $("ul", this).toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
  <li>A
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>B
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="link">Menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(this).siblings().children(".submenu:visible").toggle('slow');
```

Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submenu').hide();
  $("li:has(ul)").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().children(".submenu:visible").toggle('slow');
    $("ul", this).toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  <li>A
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>B
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
</ul>
```